# Diffeomorphism classification of manifolds with fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}_n$, $n>2$

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am looking for diffeomorphism classifications of manifolds with $\pi_1=\mathbb{Z}_n$, $n>2$. I only know of Ottenburger's PhD thesis, *A diffeomorphism classification of 5- and 7-dimensional non-simply-connected homogeneous spaces*, but I was wondering whether somebody had more examples.

Comment: In dimension $3$ those are lens spaces.  So it goes back to Reidemeister, Whitehead, etc.